# PHP PDO: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been converting my sql code to PHP PDO, and so far I have had two issues. both giving the save error

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1', `admin_active` = '0' WHERE `id` = '1' AND `agency_id` = '1' LIMIT 1' at line 1 in ....
```

This is my code:

```
    $sql  = "UPDATE `tblAgencyLocations` ";
    $sql .= "SET `location_name` = :LocationName, `address1` = :Address1, `address2` = :Address2, ";
    $sql .= "`city` = :City, `state` = :State, `zip_code` = :ZipCode, `phone1` = :Phone1, ";
    $sql .= "`phone2` = :Phone2, `fax1` = :Fax1, `email_address` = ':EmailAddress, ";
    $sql .= "`admin_active` = :LocationActive ";
    $sql .= "WHERE `id` = :AgencyLocationID AND `agency_id` = :agencyID LIMIT 1";

    $STH = $this->prepare($sql);
    $STH->bindParam(':agencyID', $agencyID);
    $STH->bindParam(':LocationName', $LocationName);
    $STH->bindParam(':Address1', $Address1);
    $STH->bindParam(':Address2', $Address2);
    $STH->bindParam(':City', $City);
    $STH->bindParam(':State', $State);
    $STH->bindParam(':ZipCode', $ZipCode);
    $STH->bindParam(':Phone1', $Phone1);
    $STH->bindParam(':Phone2', $Phone2);
    $STH->bindParam(':Fax1', $Fax1);
    $STH->bindParam(':EmailAddress', $EmailAddress);
    $STH->bindParam(':LocationActive', $LocationActive);
    $STH->bindParam(':AgencyLocationID', $AgencyLocationID);
    $STH->execute();
```

I got this same error, the other one was a select. Is there a limitation on how many times you can "Bind"? or the SQL is very long?

Thank you.

Comment: There's a limitation on how valid your SQL needs to be, as the error says... :P

Comment: i typed in the values and then tried it, it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lone quotation mark is causing a syntax error here:

```
`email_address` = ':EmailAddress
```

Comment: wooow, i looked it over maybe 12 times, i didnt even find that. thank you soo much..

Comment: Read the error message carefully. "Syntax error near ..." usually means that the character right before that position is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

in my case I was using query instead of prepare, obvious when you see it.